# error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope

Tags: c++, templates, methods, template-specialization

In the following class I try to specialize a type-erased function to an empty type for the case of default initialization. However, this yields the following `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope`. Now I've done my research and learned that gcc for some reason doesn't allow full template specialization in class scope, so consequently I would have to pull it out of the class and put it in namespace scope. However this leaves me with an even bigger misery bc as you can see the class template parameters are used to forward arguments to an external function. So I would have to templatize on that as well. but then again, I can not partially specialize function templates for the cases that Args... is a template and specialized for `empty_t` only. How do I resolve this elegantly?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:26,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:26,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename...+Ts%3E%0Avoid+myfunc(Ts...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++printf(%22Do+something!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+entity%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R,+typename...+Args%3E%0Astruct+entity%3CR(Args...)%3E%0A%7B%0A%0A++++using+fn_invoke_t+%3D+R(*)(void*)%3B%0A%0A++++struct+empty_t%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++static+R+fn_invoke(Args%26%26...+args)+%7B%0A++++++++return+myfunc(args...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++template+%3C%3E%0A++++static+R+fn_invoke%3Cempty_t%3E(Args%26%26...+args)+%7B%0A++++++++return+myfunc(args...)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++entity()%0A++++++++:+++fn_invoke_(reinterpret_cast%3Cfn_invoke_t%3E(fn_invoke%3Cempty_t%3E))%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0A++++entity(T+obj)%0A++++++++:+++fn_invoke_(+reinterpret_cast%3Cfn_invoke_t%3E(fn_invoke%3CT%3E)+)%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++fn_invoke_t+fn_invoke_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++entity%3Cvoid()%3E+hello+%3D+%5B%5D()%7B+printf(%22Hello+World!!%5Cn%22)%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++//+hello()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.804757760371345,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.19524223962866,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>


template <typename... Ts>
void myfunc(Ts... args)
{
    printf("Do something!\n");
}

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct entity;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct entity<R(Args...)>
{

    using fn_invoke_t = R(*)(void*);

    struct empty_t{};

    template <typename T>
    static R fn_invoke(Args&&... args) {
        return myfunc(args...);
    }

    template <>
    static R fn_invoke<empty_t>(Args&&... args) {
        return myfunc(args...);
    }

    entity()
        :   fn_invoke_(reinterpret_cast<fn_invoke_t>(fn_invoke<empty_t>))
    { }

    template <typename T>
    entity(T obj)
        :   fn_invoke_( reinterpret_cast<fn_invoke_t>(fn_invoke<T>) )
    { }

    fn_invoke_t fn_invoke_;
};

int main()
{
    entity<void()> hello = [](){ printf("Hello World!\n"); };

    // hello();
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:27:15: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct entity<R(Args ...)>'
   27 |     template <>
      |               ^
<source>:28:14: error: template-id 'fn_invoke<entity<R(Args ...)>::empty_t>' in declaration of primary template
   28 |     static R fn_invoke<empty_t>(Args&&... args) {
```

Comment: Specialize it outside the struct.

Comment: @273K please show how. The foo depends on Args... from the struct templates.

Comment: You might go without the specialisation and instead have an `if constexpr` inside your template such as: `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, empty_t>) { /* special code */ } else { /* general code */ }` – if need be, remove type qualifiers: `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` or with C++20 `std::remove_cvref_t<T>`.

Comment: This is actually a bug in GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One variant might be dropping the specialisation entirely in favour of an `if constexpr` inside the template such as:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, SpecificType>)
{
    /* special code */
}
else
{
    /* general code */
}
```

If need be you can remove type qualifiers like `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` or with C++20 `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` so that `const` and `volatile` types or references are treated alike.

In your case this would result in:

```
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, empty_t>)
{
    return myfunc(args...);
}
else
{
    return myfunc(args...);
}
```

Demonstation on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MrdzWh87j).

Comment: I consider this the easiest way in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can change to function template overloading instead. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T, empty_t>, R>
fn_invoke(Args&&... args) {
    return myfunc(args...);
}

template <typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, empty_t>, R>
fn_invoke(Args&&... args) {
    return myfunc(args...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/z/3eK8qaMoE)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an intermediate stage: a "helper" class template and specialize it outside of the `entity` class (your call if static function or operator() is to be used):

```cpp
struct empty_t{};

template<typename T, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct detail
{
    static R call(Args&&... args)
    {
        my_func(args...);
    }
};


template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct detail<empty_t, R, Args...>
{
    static R call(Args&&... args)
    {
        my_func2(args...);
    }
};
```

This way one can circumvent the impossiblity to partially specialize functions.

Then inside entity class:

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    static R fn_invoke(Args&&... args) {
        return detail<T, R, Args...>::call(args...);
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ehYYvnofE

Comment: The class template is not really the main thing you did to get a solution – you moved your templates out of the class in the very first place!

Comment: @Aconcagua true, but class was needed to be able to partially specialize the function, i.e. partially specialize the function by specializing the class containing it.

Comment: I don't contradict the need of a class – my point is that you missed providing the information of moving the template out of the class into the namespace in addition to (and before!) introducing this new class.